# Do branes in M-theory form closed structures or do they have an edge?

Tags: string-theory, boundary-conditions, topology, branes

In M-theory, besides strings, branes play their role. Strings can be attached to them, for example when a number of branes in a stack rotate around a common axis and the strings between them get stretched. A process which is similar to the spontaneous symmetry breaking involved in the Higgs mechanism, the symmetry of the stack being broken up and the strings acquiring stretch energy.

I have difficulty imagining how this can happen in the tiny compactified space. Are these branes just branes floating in space, like a carpet (with various dimensions)? Are they closed balloon-like structures? Are they wrapped around the the compactified space somehow, like a circle on a cylinder?